# Find a replacement for -Xbootclasspath/p option when using jdk 11

Tags: jboss, java-11, java-opts

I am upgrading to jdk 11 and from what I've noticed, the -Xbootclasspath/p option no longer exists. I've tried replacing it with -Xbootclasspath/a, I've also tried using --patch-module(although I've read that it's not recommended in production) or --add-module options instead and none of them seems to work. The reason why -Xbootclasspath/p was added in the first place is the following error:

> Could not load Logmanager "org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"

Do you have any other idea what I should try in order to replace or get rid of -Xbootclasspath/p option? Thanks!

Comment: You should try to find out what is trying to load “org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager” and why it fails. Messing around with the bootclasspath should never be the solution to this kind of problem.

Comment: What version of JBoss EAP or WildFly are you using? Also are you launching the JVM with an agent?

Comment: I am using Jboss 7.3.4 and yes, I am launching the JVM with an agent